# Is Redshift able to optimise duplicate aggregate expressions?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Let's say I have the following query:

```
SELECT sum(a), sum(b), sum(a) - sum(b)
FROM salelines
```

Hopefully it should only need to do `sum(a)` and `sum(b)` once since the third column could reuse these aggregations. Here is the `EXPLAIN`:

```
XN HashAggregate  (cost=35.21..41.90 rows=535 width=22)
  ->  XN Seq Scan on salelines  (cost=0.00..15.65 rows=1565 width=22)
```

However, the interesting thing is if I change the column to be in a form that it should not be able to optimise out:

```
SELECT sum(a), sum(b), sum(a - b)
FROM salelines
```

Firstly I get a different average cost, which would suggest the query planner is actually treating the statements differently somewhere:

```
XN HashAggregate  (cost=31.30..36.65 rows=535 width=22)
  ->  XN Seq Scan on salelines  (cost=0.00..15.65 rows=1565 width=22)
```

But what's most interesting is this query plan suggests that it should actually be faster to do it this way. I understand that the `cost` does not directly relate to the performance of the query.

My question is:

Is Redshift able to optimise out the expressions, or would it actually be faster to allow Redshift to do a third aggregate with its extreme column aggregate performance instead?

Answer (score 1):

Per your testing, looks like it doesn't optimize. At the same time, you can try to optimize it yourself:

```
WITH
totals as (
    SELECT sum(a) as sum_a, sum(b) as sum_b
    FROM salelines
)
SELECT sum_a, sum_b, sum_a-sum_b as dif_ab
FROM totals
```

That would definitely let Redshift skip the step that you'd like to skip

Answer (score 0):

Here are the results on a larger table:

```
SELECT sum(a), sum(b), sum(a) - sum(b)
FROM salelines

XN Aggregate  (cost=14455901.45..14455901.45 rows=1 width=20)
  ->  XN Seq Scan on salelines  (cost=0.00..7227950.72 rows=722795072 width=20)
```

(25.905 + 22.870 + 29.091 + 22.970 + 21.893) / 5 = 24.545 seconds

```
SELECT sum(a), sum(b), sum(a - b)
FROM salelines

XN Aggregate  (cost=12648913.77..12648913.77 rows=1 width=20)
  ->  XN Seq Scan on salelines  (cost=0.00..7227950.72 rows=722795072 width=20)
```

(22.829 + 22.162 + 23.063 + 19.526 + 22.688) / 5 = 22.054 seconds

The query planner does not give enough output to explain exactly what it's doing, but from these results it would be reasonable to say that:

`sum(a), sum(b), sum(a) - sum(b)` probably requires 4 aggregates, whereas `sum(a), sum(b), sum(a - b)` is only 3 aggregates. It would probably be safe to assume that it does not optimise away expressions like this.